# Lambda calculus in Haskell: Is there some way to make Church numerals type check?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I'm playing with some lambda calculus stuff in Haskell, specifically church numerals.  I have the following defined:

```
let zero = (\f z -> z)
let one = (\f z -> f z)
let two = (\f z -> f (f z))
let iszero = (\n -> n (\x -> (\x y -> y)) (\x y -> x))
let mult = (\m n -> (\s z -> m (\x -> n s x) z))
```

This works:

```
:t (\n -> (iszero n) one (mult one one))
```

This fails with an occurs check:

```
:t (\n -> (iszero n) one (mult n one))
```

I have played with `iszero` and `mult` with my constants and they seem to be correct.  Is there some way to make this typeable?  I didn't think what I was doing was too crazy, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your definitions are correct, as are their types, when seen at top-level. The problem is that, in the second example, you're using `n` in two different ways that don't have the same type--or rather, their types can't be unified, and attempting to do so would produce an infinite type. Similar uses of `one` work correctly because each use is independently specialized to different types.

To make this work in a straightforward way you need higher-rank polymorphism. The correct type for a church numeral is `(forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a)`, but higher-rank types can't be inferred, and require a GHC extension such as `RankNTypes`. If you enable an appropriate extension (you only need rank-2 in this case, I think) and give explicit types for your definitions, they should work without changing the actual implementation.

Note that there are (or at least were) some restrictions on the use of higher-rank polymorphic types. You can, however, wrap your church numerals in something like `newtype ChurchNum = ChurchNum (forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a)`, which would allow giving them a `Num` instance as well.

Comment: Wow, you're right.  I did not expect something so fundamental to require higher-rank polymorphism but I guess that's what comes from the lambda calculus being untyped.

Comment: @singpolyma: One could argue that higher-rank polymorphism is *itself* fundamental to a polymorphic typed lambda calculus, not the extra limitations necessary to allow full type inference.

Comment: @singpolyma: BTW,the mentioned above restrictions will come into play when you try to implement something like `mult m n = m (plus n) zero` which is a valid expression in untyped lambda but requires impredicative polymorphism in typed. Here is Oleg's workaround for that: http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#some-impredicativity

Answer (score 5):

Let's add some type signatures:

```
type Nat a = (a -> a) -> a -> a

zero :: Nat a
zero = (\f z -> z)

one :: Nat a
one = (\f z -> f z)

two :: Nat a
two = (\f z -> f (f z))

iszero :: Nat (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
iszero = (\n -> n (\x -> (\x y -> y)) (\x y -> x))

mult :: Nat a -> Nat a -> Nat a
mult = (\m n -> (\s z -> m (\x -> n s x) z))
```

As you can see, everything seems pretty normal except for the type of `iszero`.

Let's see what happens with your expression:

```
*Main> :t (\n -> (iszero n) one n)
<interactive>:1:23:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      a0
      =
      ((a0 -> a0) -> a0 -> a0)
      -> ((a0 -> a0) -> a0 -> a0) -> (a0 -> a0) -> a0 -> a0
    Expected type: Nat a0
      Actual type: Nat (Nat a0 -> Nat a0 -> Nat a0)
    In the third argument of `iszero', namely `(mult n one)'
    In the expression: (iszero n) one (mult n one)
```

See how the error uses our `Nat` alias!

We can actually get a similar error with the simpler expression `\n -> (iszero n) one n`. Here's what's wrong. Since we are calling `iszero n`, we must have `n :: Nat (b -> b -> b)`. Also, because of `iszero`s type the second and third arguments, `n` and `one`, must have the type `b`. Now we have two equations for the type of `n`:

```
n :: Nat (b -> b -> b)
n :: b
```

Which can't be reconciled. Bummer.